# How do I compare object values that are inside an array?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array containing several objects.

```
$products = [
            {"id":"1","random":"sadasd","mergethis":"Ding"},
            {"id":"2","random":"assdfsadf","mergethis":"Ding"},
            {"id":"2","random":"assdfsadf","mergethis":"Flop"},
            {"id":"2","random":"assdfsadf","mergethis":"Bips"},
            {"id":"3","random":"sdfss","mergethis":"Flung"},
            {"id":"3","random":"sdfss","mergethis":"Rorg"},
            {"id":"4","random":"asdasdddaf","mergethis":"Shwung"}
            ]
```

I'm trying to iterate trough this array and when the `id` is allready present in the array, I want to add the value of `mergethis` with the first hit that has the same `id`, seperated with a comma, and then unset the object from the array.

So my expected outcome would become:

```
[
{"id":"1","random":"sadasd","mergethis":"Ding"},
{"id":"2","random":"assdfsadf","mergethis":"Ding,Flop,Bips"},
{"id":"3","random":"sdfss","mergethis":"Flung,Rorg"},
{"id":"4","random":"asdasdddaf","mergethis":"Shwung"}
]
```

I'm trying to iterate trough `$products` and compare the values but I'm stuck at comparing the value to a subvalue of the array in stead of to the entire array

```
foreach($products as $key => $value){
    if (in_array($value->id, $products)) {
        //Delete this item and add product_category comma sepereated to first item
        //unset($products[$key]);
    }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work because it compares the item to the entire array in stead of to the sub value `id` of the array item.

How do I go about getting my expected outcome?

Do I need to create a new array filled with the keys and `id` values of each array item and iterate trough that? Or is there an easier method to compare object values inside an array to each other?

Comment: I think you have to create a new array and fill it during the foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use associative array with `id` as key and the whole product as value:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($products as $prod){
    if (array_key_exists($prod['id'], $results)){
        $results[$prod['id']]['mergethis'] .= ',' . $prod['mergethis'];
    } else {
        $results[$prod['id']] = $prod;
    }
}
```

Comment: This adds the key of the item to mergethis, instead of the mergethis value. The second `$prod['id']['mergethis']` should be `$prod['mergethis']`.
Also missing some some closing `;` and an `)` in the if statement.
But besides that, good answer =).

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($products as $value) {
    if (!isset($result[$value['id']])) {
        $value['mergethis'] = [$value['mergethis']];
        $result[$value['id']] = $value;
    } else {
        $result[$value['id']]['mergethis'][] = $value['mergethis'];
    }
}
```

This seems the most sensible. If you do need those arrays joined by commas into one string:

```
foreach ($result as &$value) {
    $value['mergethis'] = join(',', $value['mergethis'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically looking for a PHP implementation of `pluck`. Have a look at [this gist for a PHP version](https://gist.github.com/zhuan/4461793).

```
$ids_array = array_pluck("id", $products); // get just he id values
$ids_array = array_unique($ids_array); // remove duplicates
foreach($products as $key => $value){
    if (in_array($value->id, $ids_array)) {
        //Delete this item and add product_category comma sepereated to first item
        //unset($products[$key]);
    }
}
function array_pluck ($toPluck, $arr) {
    return array_map(function ($item) use ($toPluck) {
        return $item[$toPluck];
    }, $arr); 
}
```